# In JMeter, what are some good methods to handle external dependencies?

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, api-testing, good-practices

As the title says, what are some ideas for dealing with non-API request related dependencies in a JMeter test?

I have a series of tests that work with zipped-up data. The first step in the test is to unzip that data. Clearly, this takes time - including it in the JMeter test captures the results of the call to unzip alongside everything else so skews the results. Similarly, I may need to do things with data after a series of tests that don't involve API calls.

In terms of a "script", they're definitely part of the overall test - I just think they should be in the JMeter test. I could write a powershell script (or something similar) to handle those elements, which I think would work fine for running in a CI/CD pipeline but be less usable when running locally (e.g. debugging or adding new steps/tests).

Any good mechanisms which'll work nicely in both scenarios?

Comment: Just to be clear- you do want Jmeter to handle or take into consideration unzipping, handling data etc ?

Comment: @Rsf - I don't mind if JMeter handles it or not. I just don't want the time to perform those external actions to skew my results.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to unzip some files and don't want JMeter to measure this time there are multiple workarounds for this:

1. Use [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test) to prepare test data
2. Use i.e. [PreProcessors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors) to prepare test data, JMeter doesn't include the time taken by Pre/Post Processors, Timers and Assertions into the sample result unless you have [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) configured to do so
3. If above points are not applicable for any reason you can use [Filter Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) tool to remove the "unwanted" sample results which are not related to API calls